# C# objects Xaml factory method for XamlWriter

Tags: c#-4.0, factory-method, xamlreader

My class uses an image as Property (`public Image myImage`). When this class is serialized (`XamlWriter`) it works fine, reading it back gives an exception:

> 'No matching constructor found on type
>   'System.Drawing.Bitmap'. You can use
>   the Arguments or FactoryMethod
>   directives to construct this type.'
>   Line number '5' and line position '8'.

Obviously there is a constructor missing for Bitmap with ColorPalette as argument:

```
<sd:Bitmap>
  <sd:Bitmap.Palette>
    <sdi:ColorPalette /> 
  </sd:Bitmap.Palette>
</sd:Bitmap>
```

I understand that I can specify a factory method creating the bitmap somehow. I also found some articles about directives for this such as http://www.wpftutorial.net/XAML2009.html

However, I am not an expert in `Xaml` and do not understand how and where to define / declare the method on my attribute. Unfortunately i do also not find an example for this.

I expect some like

```
[FactoryMethod("XYZ")]
public Image myImage ....
```

but actually have found nothing. Any idea / example you know?

Comment: Same problem i too have. If i found solution i will tell you.

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346244/xamlparseexception-in-app-xaml-resource-strings][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346244/xamlparseexception-in-app-xaml-resource-strings