# XamlParseException in app.xaml resource strings

Tags: c#, wpf, string, xaml, resources

I have the following code in App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="PcgTools.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PcgTools.ViewModels" 
         xmlns:res="clr-namespace:PcgTools.Resources"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            ...
            <res:Strings x:Key="LocStrings"/>
        </ResourceDictionary> 
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

(The ... are some lines which I removed to make the example cleaner).

When I run the application I get the following error (directly after trying to run/debug):
(translated from Dutch so might not be 100% literally equal):

There has not been found a matching constructor in type PcgTools.Resources.Strings. You can use the instruction Arguments or FactoryMethod, to create this type.

There is a constructor in file Strings.Designer.cs:

```
namespace PcgTools.Resources {
...
public class Strings {
...

[global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute
   ("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
internal Strings() {
    }
```

However, it is generated so I cannot even change it.

Btw, without changing the code has worked (about a week ago), but then about 30% of the time when debugging it gave this error and after trying again this exception did not occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your `PcgTools.Resources.Strings` class have a public default constructor? I think it's complaining that it can't create the object because it can't find a matching constructor and since you're not using `Arguments`, it's looking for a default constructor (one with no arguments). The constructor needs to be public, not internal or private.

Since the code is generated, you'll need to find some way around this. Using the FactoryMethods thing might work. To do that, set up another class like

```
namespace PcgTools.Resources
{
    public static class StringResourceHelper
    {
        public static strings GetStringResources()
        {
            return new Resources.Strings();
        }
    }
}
```

then in your XAML you can do:

```
<res:Strings x:FactoryMethod="res:StringResourceHelper.GetStringResources" 
             x:Key="LocStrings"/>
```

Comment: Yes it has a default constructor... I have added it to the question.

Comment: It has to be public as well. I should have said that in my answer initially. I've updated my answer to say that.

Comment: I've gone ahead and added an example of how you might be able to get around this since your code is auto-generated.

Comment: I made it public and it ran... thanks. However when I change a resource string the file gets regenerated and its turning back to internal ... but: even then the application starts up. Anyway you helped me although the real problem and solution is probably somewhere else. I will accept this answer.

Comment: My comment was added after your edit ... thanks for the complete solution... I already accepted the answer though but very thanks for being complete.

Comment: x:FactoryMethod is not usable (XAML2009) but I will ask a new question about it.

Comment: Asked about xaml2009 error in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347181/how-to-fix-xaml2009-language-construct-is-not-allowed-here

Answer (score 0):

See also:

http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/did-you-know-silverlight-class

In short: do not name the namespaces .Resources
It should not be named Resources but something else otherwise you will get the error as described above.

Edit: However, it seems after changing resource strings, the overwritten file (..Designer.cs) still contains the internal instead of public constructor resulting in the error from the question.