# How to fix: XAML2009 language construct is not allowed here?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

In my App.xaml code I have the following code:

```
<Application x:Class="PcgTools.App"
    ...
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
             ...
            <res:Strings x:FactoryMethod="res:StringResourceHelper.GetStringResources" 
             x:Key="LocStrings"/>
        </ResourceDictionary> 
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I got from the VS2012 compiler an error before to use the FactoryMethod or Attribute construct. But now I get the error: Xaml2009 language construct is not allowed here.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XAML 2009 is not allowed in compiled XAML (at least not in WPF 4.0), try to move your stuff that uses 2009 constructs to a separate Resource Dictionary file.

Answer (score 19):

XAML 2009 is unfortunately useless due to lack of compiler support (although VS recognises it for some stupid reason).

See:
[MSDN doc on XAML 2009](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792007.aspx#xaml_2009_support_in_wpf_and_visual_studio)

Basically no current compiler (WPF, SL, WinRT) actually supports it. As far as I know, the only thing which supports XAML 2009 is "loose xaml", where you have a stand-alone xaml file that is opened by a browser directly (which is basically useless).

I don't know of any explanation from Microsoft outlining why on earth it isn't supported. :-(