# Parameterless Constructor Using ObservableCollection in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have edited the question.  Thanks for the comments below.

It looks like my issue was with a parameterless constructor to declare the class in XAML.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to get a parameterless constructor with an observable collection.  Please see my code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace LinkKing.Classes
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class TheLinks
    {
        public string linkID;
        public string parentID;
        public string link;
        public DateTime dateAdded;
        public int stepAdded;
        public string img;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Link")]
        public string Link
        {
            get { return link; }
            set { link = value; }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("DateAdded")]
        public DateTime DateAdded
        {
            get { return dateAdded; }
            set { dateAdded = value; }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("StepAdded")]
        public int StepAdded
        {
            get { return stepAdded; }
            set { stepAdded = value; }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("LinkID")]
        public string LinkID
        {
            get { return linkID; }
            set { linkID = value; }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("ParentID")]
        public string ParentID
        {
            get { return parentID; }
            set { parentID = value; }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("IMG")]
        public string IMG
        {
            get { return img; }
            set { img = value; }
        }

        public TheLinks(string linkID, string parentID, string link, DateTime dateAdded, int stepAdded, string img) : base()
        {
            this.Link = link;
            this.DateAdded = dateAdded;
            this.StepAdded = stepAdded;
            this.LinkID = linkID;
            this.ParentID = parentID;
            this.IMG = img;
        }
    }

    public class MyLinks : ObservableCollection<TheLinks>
    {
        public MyLinks() : base()
        {

        }
    }

}
```

The error I get is `The Type does not include any accessible constructors`.

I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: My guess is that as your Link class is missing the explicit visibility modifier, it's declared private, hence you can't see it on Xaml. Try to declare it as public instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response Karel, however I have tried declaring `MyLinks` as public and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you compiled after declaring it as public? Also, looking at your class I see you don't have a parameterless constructor defined. You'll not be able to instantiate any object in XAML without a public parameterless constructor. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347181/how-to-fix-xaml2009-language-construct-is-not-allowed-here

Comment: Hi Karel, Thanks for the thought.  I tried adding a paremeterless constructor to the class and still doesn't work.  I appreciate your help though.  I think we have narrowed it down to something with the constructor, but that's not it.

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it will not let me". Provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, and explain _exactly_ what error message you are getting. Explain also everything that you've done to try to resolve the problem, being very precise about what happened with each of those attempts and why they didn't work. See also [ask] for more information about how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: I'm totally guessing, try this: `<sf:RibbonWindow.Resources>` instead of `<Window.Resources>`.

Answer (score 1):

Just based on the code, you have no public parameterless constructor for MyLinks. If you did you would find it on *local*.

Also usually if it's MVVM, I think having a different namespace for the ViewModel would be better.

Maybe it would also make sense to make your fields (i.e. `public string linkID;public string parentID;` up to `public string img;`) private too since you don't access them from outside the class anyway.

Comment: Tyress, thanks for your response.  I have narrowed the issue down to the parameterless constructor.  I reworked the class, and now I can find it in local, but now I get an error of "the type does not include any accessible constructors".

Comment: @Cnote What does your code look like now? Can you try right-clicking on the solution and doing a rebuild to see if that will fix the problem?

Comment: Hi Tyress, I have updated my question.  I appreciate the help.  It seems I am not declaring my parameterless constructor correctly with my observable collection.

Comment: @Cnote which class do you plan to use as a ViewModel? Assuming you're going with pure WPF, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Your TheLinks class has ViewModel properties and fields but it's really acting like a model here. Best to think 1 ViewModel for 1 View to prevent it from becoming convoluted. Can't really guess why MyLinks will be a ViewModel, but TheLinks still has no parameterless constructor.

Comment: Tyrese I think that's my problem. I have a datagrid and a diagram that both use the same data. For some reason in my head I thought I could use the same viewmodel for both of them. I think MVVM is too complicated for a self taught guy.

Comment: @Cnote it's not that complicated, but you have to start from something a little simpler. Something like http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html

Comment: @Cnote To make it clear though, there's no issue having 1 VM being used by more than 1 view, and I thought what you were trying to do was use multiple ViewModels with 1 view, which doesn't have an issue either...it's just my opinion that it'll get convoluted for someone who is trying to get it to bind first.